# Keyboard hide UITextField how to solve this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

When the keyboard appears in my application it hides the UITextField.  How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you say this I assume you mean that it covers the text field. If your text field is on the bottom half of the screen, you can make an IBAction and link it to the touch down method of the text field. In the IBAction you could either move everything in the view up the height of the keyboard, or move just the text field up and put a border around it or something so the user knows it is separate from the rest of the view. Then when you hide the keyboard move everything back.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to place the text field inside a UIScrollView and move the scroll view to some point where the text field will be visible completely.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    originalScrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0. 100) animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

And get the scroll view back to its original position once the textField editing is over.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [scrollView setContentOffset:originalScrollOffset animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can moveup the view and once editing finished again move down. This post will be helpful for you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)